# Grid repeat with unique row names

Tags: css, layout, css-grid, display

I can't find the solution to this one. Maybe it does not exist but I'm trying to set grid layout using repeat `method`. One thing that is not usual in this setup is unique row names. Is there any chance to not repeat each time the names and deal with it with some generic solution?

The general idea:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(9, [start two three four five six seven eight end] 100vw);
```

The for loop idea:

```
$rows-number: 9;
@for $i from 1 through $rows-number {
    grid-template-rows: repeat($rows-number, [row-#{$i}]} 100vw);
}
```

The expected solution:

```
grid-template-rows: [start] 10vw [two] 10vw [three] 10vw [four] 10vw [five] 10vw [six] 10vw [seven] 10vw [eight] 10vw [end];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you want to repeat the same row configuration then it means that one column will contain only one area thus at the end you need only one row with 900px instead of 9 with 100px

Comment: no, I need 6x9 grid layout, but I need to define row names to set items in it

Comment: yes but based on what you are describing, you will repeat the same row names, right? which will give each column only on area since the same name is used for each row

Comment: yes, that's why I don't need the same row names, I need unique ones, i don't want `row row row row row ...`

Comment: but what you want is `"one two" "one two" "one two" ..` ? in the row you have unique names but you repeat the whole for each new row

Comment: I do add the example that I need to achieve

Comment: why not simply `repeat(9,10vw)` and you are done? since the names are unique, you aren't obliged to use names and you can rely on numbers to place your items (ex: `grid-row: 1 / 3` )

Comment: yeh, this is the "minimal" solution, but want to set easy to read implementation, maybe there's no way to do that ... thanks for help dude